# Stronger word for "trashing"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs

He was in the midst of a rampage, trashing the office.

- What could a stronger word for "trashing" be that could fit in the above sentence?
- Or could I just add "completely" before "trashing"?
- How about "completely destroying" would that work?

Comment: You can say **destroying**. Loading your description doesn't really work, because if he was 'completely destroying' the office, that is a work in progress, so it is not complete. OTOH afterwards, you could say the office was completely destroyed.

Comment: **Ransacking** fits, but tends to imply searching for something in the process

Comment: **Ravaging** sounds like someone destroying things while out of control

Answer (score 1):

All of your ideas sound good. Some other suggestions:

- **absolutely wrecking**
- demolishing
- razing cubicles to the ground
- devastating

Comment: *Wrecking* will be good if you want to communicate he is messing up stuff on desks, but not specifically trying to destroy the structural integrity of cubes.  Unless that is what's happening.